# Why is the edit text, password box and log in button not visible on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

My code looks good in the activity_main.xml but in the emulator, it lacks the email and password boxes along with the login button. Same happens when run on physical device as well. The screen looks as if there is just a logo and a gray background. This is my first time developing an app so the cause might be even really basic.

This is my xml code right now :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#A7A5A4"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="username"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.625"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            tools:targetApi="o"
            tools:text="@string/email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="password"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.056"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            tools:targetApi="o"
            tools:text="@string/password" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.116" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="410dp"
                android:layout_height="309dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/id"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/fulllogo" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Actually I have been trying to make changes to the code to remove this issue but the emulator shows no changes even though the design tab looks perfectly fine according to my code.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints don't seem to be set up correctly. First of all the email has top and bottom of parent, and the rest all go to the bottom of parent. Then the linear layout doesn't have any constraints at all and it's size is set to match_parent, so that is why it is taking up the entire screen, it is also unnecessary to have the linearlayout. Try removing it the linear layout, then putting these constraints in each one with Top_toBottomOf the view before it, and Bottom_toTopOf the one after it, kinda like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#A7A5A4"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="410dp"
            android:layout_height="309dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/id"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/fulllogo" 
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/email"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="username"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/password"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            tools:targetApi="o"
            tools:text="@string/email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="password"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            tools:targetApi="o"
            tools:text="@string/password" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you want more space betweewn specific views use `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` and/or marginBottom

Comment: Sorry but this changed the spacing in the design view. The emulator still shows same error :/

Comment: If your imageview is still taking up the entire screen then the width and height are either set match_parent or a value greater than the screen, or is still in the linearlayout with match_parent. Remove the linear layout if it is still there, and try changing the height to something small like 50dp and see if you still get the same thing

Answer (score 0):

My kind information to you. Please must avoid the drag and drop the widgets to the Design pane. It causes multiple unwanted errors while running an app. Just write the design code in text pane, this will help you to learn new things while writing the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#A7A5A4"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/id"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_text"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="@string/email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_text"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="15dp"
        tools:text="@string/password"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/email"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/password"
        android:text="@string/Button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this is will help you in some way.

Comment: Hey @gopikumar, this looks off-topic and doesn't lead anywhere. Nowhere has this been mentioned that the OP wasn't using XML. Please post answers related to the question only.